# how to color date fill of full calendar when some event title will be there instead of showing event title below to that particular date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

Hi all I want to color date of full calendar when some event title is there for that particular date like

[image]

Comment: what have you tried till now...put your code here so others can look into it

Comment: You can do it with CSS.